# autohotkey: #IfWinActive how to specify both ahk_class and ahk_exe

Tags: autohotkey

In autohotkey's `#IfWinActive` statement, is it possible to specify multiple criteria? specifically, `ahk_class` and `ahk_exe`? eg, something similar to

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe test.exe && ahk_class Test
; window specific stuff
#IfWinActive ; Test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the WinTitle parameter you can specify more than one criterion 
for narrowing down the search  of a specific window. See [**Multiple Criteria**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#multi).

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe test.exe ahk_class Test

    ; window specific definition of hotkeys or/and hotstrings

#IfWinActive ; turn off context sensitivity
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

```
F1::
    IfWinActive ahk_exe test.exe ahk_class Test
    ; do window specific stuff
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm

Comment: Never thought it's that simple. I've tried similar form but with comma in between. Thx a lot! Saved my day.

Comment: Saved my day here too! I have been looking into matching by a bit of Win-Title and the ahk_exe. Used it in Groupadd, and it worked very well!